# useState winningTags variable displays undefined

Tags: reactjs, undefined

I am using antd framework. I am trying to use data I got from  my database for the drop down but winningTags is showing undefined.

I fetched the data from the database and put the data inside winningTags variable then used the variable which contains and an array of objects to pass data to items variable which is passed to the dropdown as props

```
const TabPanel = ({ id }) => {

    const [winningTags, setWinningTags] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getWinningTags() {
            const res = await CategoryServices.getWinningTags(id);
            setWinningTags(res.data.data)
        }
        getWinningTags(id)
    }, []);

    console.log("Winning sam", winningTags)

    const items = winningTags.map(item => {
        const id = item.id
        return {
            key: id,
            label: (
                <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.antgroup.com">
                    Edit `${item.name}`
                </a>
            ),
        };
    })


    return (
        <div className="d-flex flex-wrap align-item-center">
            {winningTags && winningTags.map((winningTag) => (
                <div key={winningTag.id}>
                    <Card bordered={true} style={{ width: 300 }}>
                        <img src={sam} alt="" />
                        <div className="d-flex">
                            <div>
                                <header className='my-3 bold'>
                                    {winningTag.name}
                                </header>
                                <p>
                                    Current Price:  {winningTag.stake_price}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className=''>
                                <Dropdown
                                    menu={{
                                        items,
                                    }}
                                    placement="bottomRight"
                                >
                                    <img src={more} alt="" style={{ "height": "50px", "cursor": "pointer" }} />
                                </Dropdown>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Card>

                </div>


            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TabPanel
```

This code showing winningTags is undefined. If I remove it the one inside div is working

```
const items = winningTags.map(item => {
        const id = item.id
        return {
            key: id,
            label: (
                <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.antgroup.com">
                    Edit `${item.name}`
                </a>
            ),
        };
    })
```

Comment: `winningTags` is `undefined` by default, because you didn't set any value. Either change it to an empty array `[]` or handle this like `winningTags && winningTags.map(item => {` or `winningTags?.map(item => {`